# There are n runs and x is a probability of minimum one occurrence of a event in n runs

Tags: probability

There is one problem to implement in a module at which i m stuck . There are n runs and x is a probability of minimum one occurrence of a event in n runs. How do i implement it in a program. Can anyone help me out with it.

Answer (score 0):

look at binomial distribution of parameter n qnd p :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution

and you're looking for P(X>=1) = 1 - P(X=0)

each event is a [Bernoulli trial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_trial) .

i.e the probability of each event to occure is p, and you're doing n trials.

Therefore according to the wikipedia articles:

```
x=1-(1-p)^n
```

in python for example:

```
def B1(n,p):
   return 1-(1-p)**n
```

where p is the proba of one event to happen and n the number of trials

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for help. This will help me getting p. But i m implementing a game which has a outcome which requires the prob. of occurrence of event is x in runs. I can't directly use this p to find out whether event has occurred in every run as it will change the net probability of occurrence of event in n runs. I need to know how do i implement in code to achieve x.

Comment: @cooldude I made an error in my answer it was P(X>=1) not P(X=1) I corrected it. I'm not sure I fully understand your question. Can you try to reformulate the original question .